# How to lock a particular band from multiband raster layer for the map item in the QGIS layout

Tags: qgis, print-composer, layouts

I have the multiband raster of time-series data and created a layout with multiple map items. I set the the particular raster band for a particular map item and Lock layers.
[image]

However, when I export the layout, the raster bands are not preserved in the map items. All maps show only the most recent raster band.

Is there some workaround, how to lock a particular band from multiband raster layer for the map item? Or is it necessary to work with separate layers only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Lock layers* only locks the particular layers that are visible in the map frame, not how they are styled.

After you have selected the band to visualise, check also the option *Lock styles for layers*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Matt, how obvious. So, band selection is driven by _Layer Style_. It's clear now.

Comment: No problem. It's not obvious until you know!